# minizinc gramma error can not Dynamic calculation

Tags: minizinc

Anyone can help me to slove this gramma error?
I do know how to rewrite this code

```
constraint 
  forall(i in 1..LINENUMBER,j in 1..DAYSETNUMBER )
    (    PACKOUTCAP[i,j] -(  sum(k in 1..j)(INPUTCAP[i,k] * rate[i,k,j-k+1])) >0 );
```

Comment: I want make cumulative sum in minizinc  ，but this always error  ， j-k+1>0

Comment: Could you show the full model? What is `LINENUMBER`, `DAYSETNUMBER`, `PACKOUTCAP`, and `INPUTCAP`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment: What is your full model (with some explanation what it should do). What error do you get? Which MiniZinc version?

The following model is your code with some fictive data added. It don't give any errors, and yield a lot of solutions.

```
int: LINENUMBER = 3;
int: DAYSETNUMBER = 3;

array[1..LINENUMBER,1..DAYSETNUMBER] of var 1..10: PACKOUTCAP;
array[1..LINENUMBER,1..DAYSETNUMBER] of var 1..10: INPUTCAP;
array[1..LINENUMBER,1..DAYSETNUMBER,1..LINENUMBER] of var 1..10: rate;
constraint
   forall(i in 1..LINENUMBER,j in 1..DAYSETNUMBER )
      ( PACKOUTCAP[i,j] -(  sum(k in 1..j)(INPUTCAP[i,k] * rate[i,k,j-k+1])) >0     );
```

Regarding **cumulative sum**, here's a simple model where the array `y` contains the cumulative sum of the values in the array `x`. Perhaps that help you?

```
int: n = 5;
array[1..n] of var 1..10: x;
array[1..n] of var 1..100: y; % cumulative sum


constraint
  y[1] = x[1] /\    
  forall(i in 2..n) (
     y[i] = y[i-1] + x[i]
  )
;
```

Comment: This is indeed the answer I want，thank you @hakank

Comment: @jinzhu That's great! If you are happy with it, please accept it as an answer.